# Is there any possibility to make the following time series stationary so that an AR or ARMA model can be fitted to such time series?

Tags: python, time-series, signals, signal-processing, wavelet

I am trying to fit a highly vibrational discrete signal (considered as a time series in this case) with an autoregressive (AR) or an autoregressive and moving average (ARMA) model. The discrete signal to be processed is shown in the following figure and it seems that there exists a certain level of heteroskedasticity in the discrete time series. I have implemented differencing, log-differencing, Box-Cox transform, wavelet denoising respectively on the same time series but none of them successfully led to the stationarity of the processed time series. I wonder if such time series can be fitted with the AR or the ARMA model. If the time series can be processed with the AR/ARMA models, how can I pre-process the time series signal so that the built AR/ARMA models are stable. If not, is there any technique (in the realm of time series approaches) which can be applied to this case? Any helps or suggestions are greatly appreciated!
[image]

Comment: BTW, I mainly care about the central part of the signal which includes the peak.

Comment: The mean of this signal seems very stable (close to 0) with the increasing sampling points.